# How to create a custom ActionBar with a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, titlebar, custom-titlebar

Hi I want to create a custom ActionBar with navigation drawer in my app. In that i want to show the face of the person who logged in my app inside a circle in right side. and the navigation bar in left side.

[image].

It didn't worked with navigation drawer before.

Comment: You know how implement Navigation drawer or too I explain you on new answer?

Comment: i dont know how to do this. if u have any samples then please help me

Comment: Okay, I can help you, wait a moment I going to open new answer explaining all code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Manikandan Try it:

*The first thing you must to do is implement and create navigation drawer:*

**/res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- menu-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- slide menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] optionsMenu;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        opcionesMenu = new String[] {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"};
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, optionssMenu));
    }

    //...
}
```

*For each item on your navigationDrawer menu you need add one Layout
and one fragment.*

**fragment_1.xml (or others items on menu, fragment_2, fragment_3....)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TxtDetalle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fragment1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**and its associated class for each FragmentLayout**

**Fragment1.java (fragment2,Fragment3, Fragment4... )**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

> We have set the menu and fragments associated with each option.The
>   following will implement the logic required to respond to events menu
>   to change the form of fragment pressing each option.
>
> This is done by implementing the onItemClick ListView event menu
>   control, logic is added to the end of the onCreate () method of our
>   core business.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new Fragment3();
                    break;
            }

            FragmentManager fragmentManager =
                getSupportFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

            drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

            tituloSeccion = opcionesMenu[position];
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tituloSeccion);

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
        }
    });
}
```

> Okay, we have implemented the basic functionality, now i goint to add
>   open and close icon.

**on MainActivity too.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    tituloApp = getTitle();

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
        drawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer,
        R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tituloSeccion);
            ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tituloApp);
            ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}
```

> Now we going to add buttons on ActionBar (on your way user image)*

**on your MainActivity too**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    boolean menuAbierto = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList);

    if(menuAbierto)
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
    else
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

> With this we meet most of the recommendations of the design guide, but
>   we still have we allow the user to open by clicking on the application
>   icon from the action bar menu.
>
> To do this, at the end of onCreate () method will qualify pulsation
>   calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled icon () and setHomeButtonEnabled (),
>   and add the event onOptionsItemSelected () (in charge of processing
>   the keystrokes on the action bar, an initial call to
>   onOptionsItemSelected method () of ActionBarDrawerToggle object
>   created above, so if it returns true (mean who has managed a click on
>   the application icon) directly come out of this method.

**MainActivity too**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    //...
}
```

> Last for finish add this method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

**EDIT
ALL PROJECT:**

https://github.com/sgolivernet/curso-android-src/tree/develop/android-navigationdrawer

Comment: can u pls mail me the project?

Comment: ahaha Of course!! wait a moment please, now I give you github proyect

Comment: @Manikandan I have edited up, please try it and say me if it works

Comment: project cannot be imported to eclipse

Comment: yeah you can import witout problems, only download *.zip and import.

Comment: @Manikandan just donwload here, extract and import to eclipse: https://mega.co.nz/#!cUBjnaTL!EAWLEFbRVv4_UnM77b0w0RxIDA1YfrkQNOwsuAoH-8c

Comment: still it cannot be imported to eclipse

Comment: I can import without problems... please say me how you import.

Comment: I importing the project by File->new->project->android project from existing code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54276/discussion-between-manikandan-and-aspicas).

Comment: @Aspicas: Thanks for the detailed and simple explanation. In my project, in addition to the navigation drawer, I want to show view pager on click of one of the drawer elements. For this, I created the necessary files, but in the onCreate of MainActivity when I instantiate the pageAdapter of the view pager, I get error. Do we need to implement FragmentActivity while creating view pager ?

Comment: mmm can you make a new question to post all details in your project and write me here "question link" to see your errors? @Basher51

Comment: @Aspicas: I'm trying different ways. If I dont succeed Ill sure do. By the way I really like your answer and simple way you described how to use fragment. They default stub of android to create drawer looks more complicated. For view pager to work does the activity need to extend FragmentActivity or can we make it work in ActionBarActivity too. (Reason I ask is because, all examples on viewpager I saw the activity extends fragmentactivity)

Comment: nono, you cannot use  `ActionBarActivity` to `ViewPager`, only `fragments` or similar object like `FragmentActivity`. @Basher51

Comment: Why is this marked as correct answer? it doesn't answer the question at all, this merely modifies the default action bar associated with a navigation drawer it does not demonstrate how to create a custom action bar for a navigation drawer

Comment: @JoeMaher yes, I explain how to implement buttons on the `ActionBar`, it's the same situation with an Image, I wrote it on `> Now we going to add buttons on ActionBar (on your way user image)`

Answer (score 4):

You can add a custom view to the action bar

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
```

add put your imageView and the title you'd like

Comment: Do u have any sample for this?

Comment: check this sample . http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: Thank u so much, but how to add navigation drawer list items?

Answer (score 1):

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_back, null);


    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```